# Spring @RestController not honoring @Validated

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, maven

I recently upgraded to Spring Boot 2.7.0, and my the request body validations stopped working. From my research so far, I've learnt that the

```
 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```

is required after Spring Boot 2.3.0.

I've added the dependency and verified that it is the only validation jar on the classpath is `jakarta.validation` (not `javax.validation`).

Here's the Controller class:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("v1/services")
@Validated
public class ServiceController {
  @PutMapping(
            path = "/{id}",
            consumes = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
    )
    @Validated(OnUpdate.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Service> updateService(@PathVariable("id") int serviceId,
                                                 @Valid @RequestBody Service service) {
     // Implementation omitted for brevity
  }
}
```

Here is the domain class:

```
@Component
public class Service {

    private int id;

    NotNull(message = "Current status is required", groups = {OnCreate.class, OnUpdate.class})
    private ServiceStatus currentStatus; // The field I want to validate
}
```

My partial pom.xml:

```
<parent>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
   <version>2.7.0</version>
   <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository --
</parent>

 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
 </dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
  <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.2</version>
 </dependency>

 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
   <version>7.0.4.Final</version>
 </dependency>
```

My dependency tree:

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.3.20:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.17.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.17.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.36:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:1.3.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.3.20:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.3.20:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.30:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.13.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.13.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.13.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.13.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.13.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:9.0.63:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:9.0.63:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.3.20:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.3.20:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.3.20:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.3.20:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.3.20:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.zaxxer:HikariCP:jar:4.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.36:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:5.3.20:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.3.20:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:9.0.63:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:jar:1.6.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-webmvc-core:jar:1.6.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-common:jar:1.6.9:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-core:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |        +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.12.0:compile
[INFO] |  |        +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:jar:2.13.3:compile
[INFO] |  |        +- io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-annotations:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |        \- io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-models:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.webjars:swagger-ui:jar:4.11.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.webjars:webjars-locator-core:jar:0.50:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.13.3:compile
[INFO] +- io.github.classgraph:classgraph:jar:4.8.147:compile
[INFO] +- jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:7.0.4.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.4.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.5.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.h2database:h2:jar:2.1.212:runtime
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.7.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.7.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.7.0:test
[INFO] |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.7.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.4.8:test
[INFO] |  |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:2.4.8:test
[INFO] |  |        \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:9.1:test
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:2.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:1.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.22.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest:jar:2.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:jar:5.8.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.8.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:jar:5.8.2:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.8.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:4.5.1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.12.10:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.12.10:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:3.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:jar:4.5.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.3.20:test
[INFO] |  \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.9.0:test
[INFO] +- org.spockframework:spock-core:jar:2.1-groovy-3.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:jar:3.0.10:test
[INFO] |  \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.8.2:test
[INFO] |     +- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.2.0:test
[INFO] |     +- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.8.2:test
[INFO] |     \- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.2:test
[INFO] +- org.spockframework:spock-spring:jar:2.1-groovy-3.0:test
[INFO] +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-json:jar:3.0.10:test
[INFO] \- junit:junit:jar:4.13.2:test
[INFO]    \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:2.2:test
```

Lastly, I'm confident it's not the jakarta package because the following unit test passed:

```
import jakarta.validation.ConstraintViolation
import jakarta.validation.Validation
import jakarta.validation.Validator

def 'Null status on update should trigger violation'() {

        given: 'I have an invalid service'
        final LocalDate may4th2021 = LocalDate.of(2021, 5, 4)

        Service serviceWithoutStatus = new Service(
                id: 1,
                contractId: 2,
                dueDate: may4th2021,
                currentStatus: null, // N.B. the violation
                history: []
        )

        when: 'I validate the client'
        Validator validator = Validation.byDefaultProvider()
                .configure()
                .messageInterpolator(new ParameterMessageInterpolator())
                .buildValidatorFactory()
                .getValidator()

        Set<ConstraintViolation<Service>> violations = validator.validate(serviceWithoutStatus, OnUpdate.class)

        then: 'There should be violations'
        !violations.isEmpty()
        violations.size() == 1
    }
```

Edit: I am using Java 11

```
openjdk version "11.0.9.1" 2020-11-04 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu11.43+1015-CA (build 11.0.9.1+1-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Zulu11.43+1015-CA (build 11.0.9.1+1-LTS, mixed mode)
```

Any help would greatly be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: With ‘’’@valid’’’ you want to make sure that you always get values in your api request right? You can user ‘’’@Required’’’ and see if that solves your problem.

Comment: @PriyeshJakhmola `@Valid` should make the controller method validate that the request body has the necessary field. I looked for a `@Required` but if you're referring to `org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Required` it's deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

This issue was that the `jakarta.validation-api` does not work with `@Validated`. I had to use `javax.validation`

The code worked as expected after I removed the below dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
  <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.2</version>
 </dependency>

 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
   <version>7.0.4.Final</version>
 </dependency>
```